# How can I "fake" a url to an html page from an html string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

On my React website, I'd like to generate an image from an html string.
I've found [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) which seems stable and popular, but it requires a URL to the page of which I want to take a screenshot of.
How can I generate a "fake" URL to give it?
The HTML string I have is basically a design of the image I want but the content depends on user input.

EDIT: (added the HTML string)

This is my HTML string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <div style="width:500px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:white' \
         ';"><div> <div style="padding:50px"> <p ' \
         'style="color:#9F9F9F;font-size:13px;font-family:verdana;margin-top:0px">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> <p ' \
         'style="color:#3F3F3F;font-size:26px;font-weight:900;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:18px;font-family' \
         ':verdana">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> <p style="color:#3F3F3F;font-size:15px;font-weight:500;margin-top:0px;font-family' \
         ':verdana">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> </div> <div style="width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#EFF5F8;"></div><div ' \
         'style="padding:50px"> <p style="color:#9F9F9F;font-size:13px;font-family:verdana">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> <p ' \
         'style="color:#3F3F3F;font-size:15px;font-weight:500;margin-top:0px;font-family:verdana">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> ' \
         '</div></div> <div style="width:100%;height:55px;background-color:#313131;margin-right:0px;margin-left' \
         ':0px;line-height:55px;"> <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size:15px;font-weight:500;font-family:verdana' \
         ';margin-left:50px">VARIABLEVARIABLE</p> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

So I get data fom the server, then replace where I wrote `VARIABLEVARIABLE` with some of the data and I want to present it to the user as an image.

EDIT 2 :
Reading the comment from @programoholic I think that he's right and I got it wrong. I kept seeing dataUrl but I understand now that it's not an actual URL that needs to be passed, but just a reference to the node in which the HTML exists.
I'm still unsure how to approach this, but it does change the question.
I'll try to set the html to the node once I get the data and then take a snap of that, maybe that'll work.

Comment: can you give us a sample code?

Comment: @Apostolos I've added the HTML string hope that helps. As far as the React part i don't have code yet as I'm not sue how to approach it, just a simply read operation from my backend.

Comment: Which url are you're talking about ? I don't see it in the documentation

Comment: @programoholic I think you're right and I got it wrong. I kept seeing `dataUrl` but I understand now that it's not an actual URL that needs to be passed, but just a reference to the node in which the HTML exists. Still unsure how to approach this, but it does change the question.

Comment: @Tsabary. I'm adding an answer

Comment: @Tsabary. check my answer :).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73850491/8175467

Comment: @programoholic looks like this might be the go trying it out and reporting back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html-to-string` doesn't require any `url`. Instead you can use the `useRef` to select the node and then generate the html content as an image like below :

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { toPng } from 'html-to-image';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    if (ref.current === null) {
      return;
    }

    toPng(ref.current, { cacheBust: true })
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.png';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :) p</p>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}> download png </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the. : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rk8g6f?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

[html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) wants base64 url , so you can create image to base64 with javascript code.

```
    const base64Convertor = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some JavaScript to replace the contents of some HTML elements with the value of your variable, which can be taken from a URL parameter.

Then pass the URL with the value in the parameter.
Eg: `/generate-image.html?variable=Hello`

```js
// Get variable from URL query params
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const variable = urlSearchParams.get('variable') || 'default value';

// Update all HTML elements with data-variable
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-variable]');
for (element of elements) {
  element.textContent = variable;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-variable="true"></h1>
<p data-variable="true"></p>
```

Comment: Answering without understanding the question being asked :)

Comment: Yeah I kind of realised I probably didn't understand the question well. I assumed html-to-image was a website, but realised it's an NPM package. Oh well, I'll leave the answer up for now